# Php file not running at specific time by terminal

Tags: php, console

It's the mac terminal.

If I write: `php test.php` it works. (It puts the current date in a file)

But if I write:

```
$ echo "php test.php" | at 15:30
```

or

```
$ at 15:30
php test.php
(ctrl D)
```

In both ways, it prints `job x at Sun Nov 24 15:30:00 2013`, and it doesn't work at 15:30.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps `php` is not in your path? What happens if you give the full path the the PHP binary?

Comment: It still doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In man of 'at':

> Note that at is implemented through the launchd(8) daemon periodically
>   invoking atrun(8), which is disabled by default.  See atrun(8) for
>   informa-tion about enabling atrun.

Do you enable it?

Comment: Thanks, it works by typing `$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist`